# Has anyone published "swap maps" for the game Y?

Tags: y

I'm referring to [the hex-grid triangular boards, not the commercial board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_%28game%29).

Wikipedia has [an article on the swap rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie_rule), and I'm wondering whether-or-not the correct

choices are published for small Y boards, like they are for not-too-large [Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)) boards. ​ [[<9]](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/091.pdf) [[=9]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.472.6072&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I just finished working them out by hand for up to 6 hexes per side

(which is 21 hexes total), but have not yet gone any further.

Comment: "Has anyone published X?" sounds to me like a game recommendation (or rather, a game supplement recommendation). I'm voting to close the question since those are off-topic.

Comment: To me it sounds more like looking for game resources